# Counting categorical variables across large number of columns

Tags: r

I've done a fair amount of searching through SO and have not found or perhaps have not understood the solution to the following question. I have the following example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Day = c('Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3'),
  WBC.esc = c('Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No'),
  WBC.deesc = c('No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes'),
  WBC.cdm = c('Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes'),
  Hgb.esc = c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'),
  Hgb.deesc = c('No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes'),
  Hgb.cdm = c('No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No'),
  Plt.esc = c('No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No'),
  Plt.deesc = c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes'),
  Plt.cdm = c('Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes'))

#   Day WBC.esc WBC.deesc WBC.cdm Hgb.esc Hgb.deesc Hgb.cdm Plt.esc Plt.deesc Plt.cdm
# 1 Day 1     Yes        No     Yes     Yes        No      No      No       Yes     Yes
# 2 Day 2     Yes        No     Yes      No       Yes      No      No       Yes     Yes
# 3 Day 3     Yes        No     Yes     Yes        No      No     Yes        No     Yes
# 4 Day 1      No        No     Yes      No        No      No      No        No     Yes
# 5 Day 2      No       Yes     Yes     Yes        No      No      No       Yes     Yes
# 6 Day 3      No       Yes     Yes      No       Yes      No      No       Yes     Yes
```

Days represent the number of days a patient has been in the hospital. The other column names refer to types of orders. I would like to answer the question of whether there were orders made ("Yes") in any of the WBC/Hgb/Plt.esc or WBC/Hgb/Plt.deesc categories. In the large dataset there are other prefixes before *.esc such as HeartRate.esc, BP.esc so just searching on the .esc suffix won't work. I know how to do this inefficiently by specifying each column name. Using the following code:

```
sum(df$Day=="Day 1" & (df$WBC.esc=="Yes" | df$WBC.deesc=="Yes" | df$Hgb.esc=="Yes" | df$Hgb.deesc=="Yes" | df$Plt.esc=="Yes" | df$Plt.deesc=="Yes"))

# [1] 1
```

This gives the correct answer of 1.

I have referenced the columns by their numbers which saves me from using the full column name (ex: `dt[,2]` instead of `dt$WBC.esc`) but even this seems prohibitively tedious when in my actual data set there are sometimes 40-50 columns to reference. In the full data set I would like to be able to do something like the following (using excel terminology here since that's what I'm familiar with, with alphabets being column names). The idea being that it will take a row, look through all the specified columns in that row for a "Yes" value and if it finds it, count it as a 1 or if it does not find "Yes" then count it as a 0.

```
countif(B:E=="Yes" | H:Y=="Yes" | AE:AG=="Yes")
```

I also tried this as:

```
sum(df$Day=="Day 1" & (dt[,2:3]=="Yes" | df[,5:6]=="Yes" | df[,8:9]=="Yes"),na.rm=TRUE)
```

which does not work as it returns an answer of "2" suggesting that it is counting each "Yes." Also this function does not run unless the number of columns reference in each is uneven such as `dt[,2:4] | dt[,8:9]` in which case I get:

> "Error: binary operation on non-conformable arrays"

I've searched through a number of questions but in the posts I've seen the column names are individually listed out, not referred to in aggregate. How can I perform this operation referencing multiple sets of adjacent columns without having to list each variable separately?

Comment: I edited my post to reflect that in the large dataset there are multiple other prefixes to .esc or .deesc so just searching on these terms alone will pull in other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
df$anyyes <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) any(x=="Yes"))
```

which results in the following dataframe:

```
> df
    Day WBC.esc WBC.deesc WBC.cdm Hgb.esc Hgb.deesc Hgb.cdm Plt.esc Plt.deesc Plt.cdm anyyes
1 Day 1     Yes        No     Yes     Yes        No      No      No       Yes     Yes   TRUE
2 Day 2     Yes        No     Yes      No       Yes      No      No       Yes     Yes   TRUE
3 Day 3     Yes        No     Yes     Yes        No      No     Yes        No     Yes   TRUE
4 Day 1      No        No     Yes      No        No      No      No        No     Yes   TRUE
5 Day 2      No       Yes     Yes     Yes        No      No      No       Yes     Yes   TRUE
6 Day 3      No       Yes     Yes      No       Yes      No      No       Yes     Yes   TRUE
```

---

If you want a specific selection of columns, e.g. only the columns ending at `.esc`, you could do:

```
df$esc.yes <- apply(df[grep("\\.esc", names(df))], 1, function(x) any(x=="Yes"))
```

which gives:

```
> df
    Day WBC.esc WBC.deesc WBC.cdm Hgb.esc Hgb.deesc Hgb.cdm Plt.esc Plt.deesc Plt.cdm esc.yes
1 Day 1     Yes        No     Yes     Yes        No      No      No       Yes     Yes    TRUE
2 Day 2     Yes        No     Yes      No       Yes      No      No       Yes     Yes    TRUE
3 Day 3     Yes        No     Yes     Yes        No      No     Yes        No     Yes    TRUE
4 Day 1      No        No     Yes      No        No      No      No        No     Yes   FALSE
5 Day 2      No       Yes     Yes     Yes        No      No      No       Yes     Yes    TRUE
6 Day 3      No       Yes     Yes      No       Yes      No      No       Yes     Yes   FALSE
```

If you want to exclude the `cdm` column, you can use:

```
df$no.cdm <- apply(df[-c(1,grep("cdm", names(df)))], 1, function(x) any(x=="Yes"))
```

Note that I added `-1` because also the first column has to be excluded.

Comment: I only want to look at select columns (WBC.esc, WBC.deesc, Hgb.esc, Hgb.deesc, Plt.esc, Plt.deesc) but not others (WBC.cdm, etc). It seems like this code will evaluate all columns. Is there a way to modify to examine select columns in a data frame?

Answer (score 0):

If we need to check only the column names with suffix 'esc/deesc', create a numeric index using `grep`, subset the columns of 'df' (`df[i1]`), get a logical matrix by comparing with 'Yes' ('m1'), `split` the sequence of columns of 'm1' by the prefix of column names of 'm1', subset, get the `rowSums`, use `Reduce` with `+` to get the sum of corresponding elements. Convert to a logical vector by double negating, and get the `sum` of TRUE values grouped by 'Day' to get the expected output.

```
 i1 <- grep('(esc|deesc)$', colnames(df))
 m1 <- df[i1]=='Yes'
 tapply(!!Reduce(`+`,lapply(split(1:ncol(m1), 
    sub('\\..*', '', colnames(m1))), function(i)
         rowSums(m1[,i]))), df$Day, FUN=sum)
 # Day 1 Day 2 Day 3 
 #   1     2     2
```

Comment: This definitely works for this particular sample data set. My larger dataset though has other columns that include the suffixes esc and deesc (referring to other lab tests and vital signs findings) that I would not want to include in this calculation. Perhaps I could slice the dataset first then run this code?

Comment: @Kiddecks  Anyway, I coded it based on the description in your post.

Comment: I understand that, I see now how my description was potentially misleading and have now amended it to hopefully better reflect the question. Thanks for your help